# Pasting a string on every other element of a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
test <- c("a","b","c","d")
test
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

And I would like to paste a string, e.g. "_2", onto every other element of the vector, to get this:

```
"a" "b_2" "c" "d_2"
```

I tried this command:

```
ifelse(test %in% seq(1, length(test), 2), test, paste(test, "_2", sep=""))
```

but this just gives me:

```
"a_2" "b_2" "c_2" "d_2"
```

which is wrong. Any suggestions on how to properly do this? Thank you!

Comment: You're checking if the values are equal to odd numbers but you need to check if the index of them is odd. Right now, a != 1,3,5 , ... and also b != 1,3,5, ... so all of them get the _2 pasted at the end of them.

Comment: @Masoud I see, I understand the problem! What would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
paste0(c("a","b","c","d"), c("", "_2"))

[1] "a"   "b_2" "c"   "d_2"
```

Comment: Your solution somehow gives more flexibility.

Comment: ... not sure what you mean. Clarify?

Comment: Just a compliment. It's easier to read and also edit. If someone wants the values to be pasted in different order than "every other" or to paste different values for odd and even indices, your solution can still cover that. +1

Comment: Ah... thanks! (need more coffee this morning, apparently)

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be,

```
test[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- paste0(test[c(FALSE, TRUE)], '_2')
test
#[1] "a"   "b_2" "c"   "d_2"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c("a","b","c","d")
x[seq(2, length(x), by=2)] <- paste0(x[seq(2, length(x), by=2)], "_2")
x
```

this gives:

```
"a"   "b_2" "c"   "d_2"
```